# How to combine mutate when the condition is the same but output is different?

Tags: r, dplyr

For my data frame, in the column Unit, if "mg" is found, it is replaced with "g" and then the corresponding value in the column "Mass" is divided by 1000. I used mutate twice to achieve this. Is there any ways to combine the two mutate into one?

```
df %>% mutate(unit = case_when(unit == "mg" ~ "g"))
df %>% mutate(mass = case_when(unit == "mg" ~ mass / 1000))
```

Comment: The second line will fail because the type will be different.  Did you meant `mutate(mass = .`

Comment: Oh yes you're right, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can include several transformations (in this case the two transformations) inside the same `mutate` call, with a reversed order. If your case_when statement is that simple, `ifelse` is enough:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(mass = ifelse(unit == 'mg', mass / 1000, mass), 
              unit = ifelse(unit == 'mg', 'g', unit))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the logical condition as a column and reuse.  As the replacement values are different, it is better to have it separately.  Also, `case_when` by default changes the rest of the elements to `NA`.  If the OP meant to keep the rest of the values from the original column, specify the `TRUE ~` condition

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
   mutate(i1 = unit == 'mg', 
      unit = case_when(i1 ~ 'g', TRUE ~ unit), 
      mass = case_when(i1~ mass/1000, TRUE ~ mass), i1 = NULL)
```